# Meaning and usage of the slang "gold"

Tags: meaning, slang

I often hear the word *gold* as a slang to describe something great such as "last night's party was gold" or "that movie was gold" etc. What exactly does *gold* mean and how do you use the slang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is commonly referred to as merit and stems from the rarity of gold and its use in medallions such as "Gold Medals." (Even this very Q&A board uses Gold / Silver / Bronze in its token system)

It is closest described as "priceless" when used in the context you described.

Comment: I don't know that "priceless" is necessarily the correct word.  Gold may be valuable, but certainly isn't priceless.

Comment: I think the meaning **in this context** is the same, ie "of the highest quality".